# CMake 3.0.2 Setup warning

Tags: installation, cmake, warnings

While installing CMake 3.0.2 on Windows7, I got the collowing warning:
[image]

What exactly does this mean and why did I get the error?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the bottom of the image, you will find `Nullsoft Instant System v2.46` , this means that your setup is built using [NSIS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nsis/) , this is a bug of NSIS, not CMake , see [this](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=11931) to  solve your problem.
 you can try this steps:

- backup your PATH variable (to some text file).
- reduce your PATH variable to the minimum, for example, to contain only (C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;).
- try to install CMake.
- if you got a successful installation, restore your PATH value to the old value plus the new values that were added to the PATH by installation.

   **Note** : there are two variables named *PATH* , one for *user* and the other for *system*.